# How to automate Teamcity installations?

Tags: teamcity

I'm using [Kennedy Oliveria's](https://github.com/kennedyoliveira/jetbrains-teamcity-docker)  incredibly helpful Docker image to create a Teamcity installation.

Is there any way to further automate the installation to include the steps that are currently manual:

- Creating an admin account
- Adding LDAP authentication
- Setting up my project

I would like a completely scripted and reproducible process for my Teamcity installation.